# Django annotating with a first element of a related queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models

#### Problem

I am creating a database model for a simple forum. Users should be able to create threads, add posts and post an image with their post.

In a view I would like to display all threads and:

- get the fields of the first post in the thread to show a part of the post/creation date etc (including an optional image)
- get the time of the last post in the thread
- count posts in a thread
- count the images in a thread

I believe this is not really possible without executing `n` queries for `n` threads, so the real question is how to redesign the database to make that possible.

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    sticky = models.BooleanField()
    ...

class Post(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey('Thread')
    image = models.OneToOneField('Image', null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    ...

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(...)
    ...
```

#### My partial solution

At this point I know how to count posts and images but I have no idea how to fetch the first post at the same time. I thought about adding additional field in the `Thread` model linking to the first `Post`.

My query which forces me to download first posts separately:

```
Thread.objects.annotate(
    replies=Count('post'),
    images=Count('post__image'),
    last_reply=Max('post_date')
)
```

Comment: see this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/38131573/2863603 for how to bring first related item

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a `Subquery` to annotate on a single field from the most recent related object:

```
comments = Comment.objects.filter(
    post=OuterRef('pk')
).order_by('-timestamp').values('timestamp')
Post.objects.annotate(
    last_comment_time=Subquery(comments[:1])
)
```

You could annotate on several fields this way, but that would hurt performance (each correlated subquery runs separately, and for each row, which is better than N+1 queries, but worse than a single join).

You can build up a JSON object on a single field, and then annotate that on:

```
comments = Comment.objects.filter(
    post=OuterRef('pk')
).annotate(
    data=models.expressions.Func(
        models.Value('author'), models.F('author'),
        models.Value('timestamp'), models.F('timestamp'),
        function='jsonb_build_object',
        output_field=JSONField()
    ),
).order_by('-timestamp').values('data')
```

(It's even possible to get the whole object as JSON, and then re-inflate that in Django, but that's a bit hacky).

---

Another solution could be to fetch the most recent comments seperately, and then combine them with the posts:

```
comments = Comment.objects.filter(
    ...
).distinct('post').order_by('post', '-timestamp')
posts = Post.objects.filter(...).order_by('pk')

for post, comment in zip(posts, comments):
    pass
```

You would need to make sure the posts and comments are in the same order here: these queries are. This would also fail if there was not a comment on each post.

A workaround for that could be to put the comments into a dict keyed by post id, and then fetch the matching one for each post.

```
comments = {
    comment.post_id: comment
    for comment in Comment.objects.distinct('post').order_by('post', '-timestamp')
}
for post in Post.objects.filter(...):
    top_comment = comments.get(post.pk)
    # whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of what you're looking for is [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#select-related). You'll also need to use `annotate` like you expected.

```
# I assume you have thread_id given to you.
last_reply = Post.objects.annotate(
    thread_images=Count('thread__post_set__image__id', distinct=True),
    replies=Count('thread__post_set__id', distinct=True),
).select_related('thread').filter(thread__id=thread_id).order_by('-post_date').first()
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I hoped to accomplish. Is there any way to select more records? As I said it would be great to display a preview of a first post in a thread while showing the list of *all* created threads. This solution forces me to filter by the thread_id thereby getting only one result.

Comment: You could fetch a single post of each thread and zip the two collections together.