# Django Custom model method with additional parameters

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am building a bike rental ap.

**frontend:** user selects the start and end dates and get all the available bikes in a list view, bikes with categories and appropriate price.

**Price:** price is calculated on 2 conditions. Vehiclecategory and duration.(as price has duration slabs.

1-3 days = 145$ sporty

1-3 days = 145$ scooter

4-7 days = 2004 sporty

4-7 days = 2004 scooter etc.

Duration can only be achieved from the chosen dates from the form in front-end, which gets converted to days.

I need to pass these days as **duration** to get the appropriate price and display it under each category accordingly in a list view.

MODELS.PY

class VehicleCategory:

```
@property
    def price(self, duration):
        for item in VehiclePrice.objects.all():
            If item.vehicle_category.title == self.title and (duration >= item.slab.start and duration <= item.slab.end):
            return item.net_price
```

VIEWS.PY

class HomeView(ListView):

```
template_name = 'app/home.html'

def get(self, request): 


    if request.method == "GET":
        start_date =  request.GET.get('start_date')
        end_date =  request.GET.get('end_date')

        if start_date and end_date:
            start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%m/%d/%Y").date()
            end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%m/%d/%Y").date()

            duration = (end_date - start_date).days +1



        vehiclecategory= VehicleCategory.objects.all()

        context = {
            'vehiclecategory1': vehiclecategory.filter(main_category= 'E-Cycle'),
            'vehiclecategory2': vehiclecategory.filter(main_category= 'E-Scooter'),
            'form':CartQuantityForm(),
            'dateform': DateForm()
        }


    return render(request, self.template_name, context )
```

here I get the duration, how can I pass this in the model method price parameter and get the above Queryset to work????"""

Comment: If you want `price()` to be a method, remove the `@property` decorator. You can't pass a parameter to a property unless you defined an extra setter, but that's most likely not what you want to use.

Comment: alright, I just need to add price to the model VehicleCategory, do u think I can add a field in model and write a method?

Comment: Do you want *all* your categories to be shown or only those with a certain price?

Comment: all categories. cos all categories will have a price.

Answer (score 1):

From the informations you gave the price needs the following conditions to be true:

- VehiclePrice.title == VehicleCategory.title
- VehiclePrice.slab.start <= duration
- VehiclePrice.slab.end >= duration

Note that with `@property` you can't pass arguments to your function since you will call it with `obj.price` instead of `obj.price(duration)`.

This would result in the following QuerySet:

```py
def price(self, duration):
    return VehiclePrice.objects.filter(
        title=self.title,
        slab__start__lte=duration,
        slab__end__gte=duration).first()
```

This returns the first object that meets this conditions. Note that if no prices are found `first()` returns `None` according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#first).

If you want to call this method in your template you have to create a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters) and pass duration to that tag in order to return the price.

Another option is to get all the categories in your view and fetch the depending prices with them.

You can also work with annotate to attach the price-object to your model, for that maybe the following links help:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47725075/6836173
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/38131573/6836173

Answer (score -1):

Views.py

```
template_name = 'app/home.html'

def get(self, request): 


    if request.method == "GET":
        start_date =  request.GET.get('start_date')
        end_date =  request.GET.get('end_date')

        vehiclecategory= VehicleCategory.objects.all()

        if start_date and end_date:
            start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%m/%d/%Y").date()
            end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%m/%d/%Y").date()

            duration = (end_date - start_date).days +1
            vehiclecategory = vehiclecategory.filter(slab__start__lte=duration, slab__end__gte=duration)


        context = {
            'vehiclecategory1': vehiclecategory.filter(main_category= 'E-Cycle'),
            'vehiclecategory2': vehiclecategory.filter(main_category= 'E-Scooter'),
            'form':CartQuantityForm(),
            'dateform': DateForm()
        }


    return render(request, self.template_name, context )
```

Comment: ok, but my question is, how to I pass the duration parameter to the method?

Comment: you can pass parameter like this `vehicle|custom_tag:duration`, where `vehicle` is your object, `custom_tag` is your custom template tag and `duration` is parameter which you want to pass.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. I think you don't need that method at all. Can you share you full listview class?

Comment: my post has the full list view class