# How to sort distinct values with respect to manytoone class in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two models

```
class MessageThread(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    created_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='created_user')
    belonging_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    last_message_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

and

```
class Message(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(MessageThread, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=500)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Here, I want to get MessageThreads that are sorted by their last Messages' create_date.

I tried to get sorted Messages by '-create_date' and then get distinct thread ids from that query but it doesnt work. I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: This thread might be of interest - "Django annotating with a first element of a related queryset": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23629431/django-annotating-with-a-first-element-of-a-related-queryset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order by the maximum of the `message__created_date`, so:

```
from django.db.models import F, Max

MessageThread.objects.alias(
    last_message=Max('message__create_date')
).order_by(F('last_message').desc(nulls_last=True))
```

You should *not* have a field `last_message_date` in the `MessageThread` model: you can determine this dynamically, when needed.

---

> **Note**: Django's [**`DateTimeField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField)
> has a [**`auto_now_add=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField.auto_now_add)
> to work with timestamps. This will automatically assign the current datetime
> when creating the object, and mark it as non-editable (`editable=False`), such
> that it does not appear in `ModelForm`s by default.

---

> **Note**: Ordering with `NULL`s depends on the database backend. You can work with [**`.desc(nulls_last=True)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.Expression.desc) to ensure that the NULLs will be put last when ordering in descending order.

Comment: thanks for this great answer. One more question. How to get this for messages that their create_date is below certain date. `(MessageThread.objects.filter(Q(created_user=request.user)|Q(belonging_user=request.user),message__create_date__lte=before_date_time)).alias(last_message=Max('message__create_date')).order_by(F('last_message').desc(nulls_last=True))` doesnt work for me

Comment: @BurakEr: what do you mean with "below", is that "older" or "newer"?

Comment: I mean older ones.

Comment: @BurakEr: what is not working?

Comment: @WilliemVanOnsem I have solved the problem that was because my database inconsistency.